# How can I trigger same Cloud Run job/service using different arguments?

Tags: python, scrapy, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to make a scrapy scraper work using cloud run. The main idea is that every 20 minutes a cloud scheduler cron should trigger the web scraper and get data from different sites. All sites have the same structure, so I would like to use same code and parallelize the execution of the scraping job, doing something like `scrapy crawl scraper -a site=www.site1.com` and `scrapy crawl scraper -a site=www.site2.com`.

I have already deployed a version of the scraper, but it only can do `scrapy crawl scraper`. How can I do that at execution the command's site change?

Also, should I be using cloud run job or service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that [page of documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs), there is a trick.

- Define a number of task, let's say, you set the number of task equal to the number of site to scrap. use the --task parameter for that
- In your container (or in Cloud Storage, but if you do that, you have to download the file before starting the process), add a file with 1 website to scrap per line.
- At runtime, use the `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` environment variable. That variable indicate the number of the task in the execution. For each different number, pick a line in your file of websites (the number of the line equal to the env var value).

Like that, you can leverage Cloud Run jobs and parallelism.

---

The main tradeoff here is the static form of the websites list to scrap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @guillaume. I thought about this but how can I deal when the number of websites increases? I should edit the number of tasks manually? Or maybe use something like itertools and cycle through the websites and `CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX` and repeat until done?

Comment: Yes, a solution is to have the max number of task somewhere (in a parameter of env var) and process all the line number equals to `i * maxTask + CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX`. Like that you cycle over the line and stop when you are out of index of your website list

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in [overrides](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#override-job-configuration). For example, when calling a job from the `cloud` cli sdk, you can pass [`args`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/jobs/execute#:%7E:text=FLAGS-,%2D%2Dargs,-%3D%5BARG%2C%E2%80%A6%5D), which can contain alternative args to be passed to your script